# Layering text and images on JToggleButton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtogglebutton

I'm trying to make a JToggleButton with icons for the toggled on and toggled off states. The icons work just fine, but they cover up the text even when I make the center of the toggled off state transparent.

This is my code for the button, in a constructor for a class extending JToggleButton

```
public SettingsButton(String text) {
        super.setText(text);
        super.setIcon(disabledIcon);
        super.setSelectedIcon(enabledIcon);
        super.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        super.setFont(settingsButtonsFont);
    }
```

It looks like this disabled (should have text reading "English to Spanish"):
[disabled]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/95geH.png]

and like this enabled (should have text reading "Spanish to English"):
[enabled]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUEqy.png]

I tried to set the background to white, and I tried to use setComponentZOrder(). I found that this didn't work because it only works for components in the frame, not the parts of a button.

Is there a way to layer the text of the button above its icons so it's visible in both states?

Comment: Consider providing a [mcve]

Comment: 1) Why are you extending JToggleButton? You should only extend a class to add functionality, not set properties of the class. 2) *but they cover up the text* - by default the text is painted to the right of the Icon. If you don't see the text, my guess is you are using a null layout and the text is truncated. 3) *Is there a way to layer the text of the button above its icons so it's visible in both states?* - think you looking for setHorizontalTextPosition(...) and setVerticalTextPosition(...). When set to CENTER the text will be painted in the center of the Icon.